# How to write a large number of nested records in JSON with Python

Tags: python, json, records

I want to produce a JSON file, containing some initial parameters and then records of data like this:

```
{
 "measurement" : 15000,
 "imi" : 0.5,
 "times" : 30,
 "recalibrate" : false,
 {
  "colorlist" : [234, 431, 134]
  "speclist" : [0.34, 0.42, 0.45, 0.34, 0.78]
 }
 {
  "colorlist" : [214, 451, 114]
  "speclist" : [0.44, 0.32, 0.45, 0.37, 0.53]
 }
 ...
}
```

How can this be achieved using the Python json module? The data records cannot be added by hand as there are very many.

EDIT: Solved with help from @Aprillion. Here is the resulting code as in the program:

```
data=[]
i=0
while i<measurement:
  data.append({"colorlist" : listcolorlist[i], "speclist" : listspeclist[i]})
  i+=1
python_data = {
  "measurement" : measurement,
  "imi" : imi,
  "times" : times,
  "recalibrate" : recalibrate,
  "data": data
}
print(json.dumps(python_data, indent=4))
```

Comment: Read the json module documentation.

Comment: @OP: Apart from showing us what you have tried, please be specific in asking. What do you want exactly?

Comment: I find your json example source strange.  Are you sure about those equal signs and the nested somewhat-dict-looking things with them inside?  Shall they be values or keys of the surrounding?

Comment: I've tried using a dictionary within a dictionary, but this doesn't work as I need the colorlist and speclist values to be tied together as shown.

Comment: @jamesmcm dictionary needs `key: value` pairs, see my answer for a correct data format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) you use invalid json format in your question
b) exept `False` vs. `false` python data formats will be exactly the same as JSON in this example

***UPDATE**: code based on updated question (using [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead of while loop):*

```
import json
measurement = 2
listcolorlist = [[234, 431, 134],
                 [214, 451, 114]]
listspeclist = [[0.34, 0.42, 0.45, 0.34, 0.78],
                [0.44, 0.32, 0.45, 0.37, 0.53]]
python_data = {"measurement" : 15000,
               "imi" : 0.5,
               "times" : 30,
               "recalibrate" : False,
               "data" : [{"colorlist" : listcolorlist[i],
                          "speclist" : listspeclist[i]}
                         for i in range(measurement)]}
print(json.dumps(python_data))
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixes the formatting problems, now I will just need to write a for loop to repeat the extraction of the arrays from the python lists.

Comment: well, if you need help with that, update the question or post a new one to include your original data, i don't have a fortune teller crystal ball you know (otherwise, please accept the answer if you found out what you asked for)

Comment: Yeah, sorry I was busy at work. In case anyone else has a similar issue, this what the exact resulting code looks like:
    data=[]
    i=0
    while i<measurement:
      print i
      data.append({"colorlist" : listcolorlist[i], "speclist" : listspeclist[i]})
      i+=1
      python_data = {
       "measurement" : measurement,
       "imi" : imi,
       "times" : times,
       "recalibrate" : recalibrate,
       "data": data
       }
      print(json.dumps(python_data, indent=4))

Comment: i updated my answer too, in case anyone will find list comprehensions more elegant than while loops (might save memory and a very few processor cycles as well)

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
print json.dumps([ {
    "measurement%d" % i : 15000,
    "imi%d" % i : 0.5,
    "times%d" % i : 30,
    "recalibrate%d" % i : False,
} for i in range(10) ])
```